# Redocly x-codeSamples Referenced File?

Tags: openapi, redoc

In Redocly, how is it possible to reference an external file in an x-codeSamples tag? The Redocly reference guide: https://redoc.ly/docs/api-reference-docs/vendor-extensions/redoc-supported-extensions/#x-codesamples

In the following example, the first case ('Example request') renders properly. The second case ('Schema'), renders only as "[object object]". Does this tag support $ref statements?

```
x-codeSamples:
    - lang: 'Example request'
      source: |
        PetStore.v1.Pet pet = new PetStore.v1.Pet();
        pet.setApiKey("your api key");
    - lang: 'Schema'
      source:
        $ref: ../components/schemas/Test_schema.yaml
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you still need it, but you could try with the scheme definition tag, do something like:

```
x-codeSamples:
    - lang: 'Example request'
      source: |
        PetStore.v1.Pet pet = new PetStore.v1.Pet();
        pet.setApiKey("your api key");
    - lang: 'Schema'
      source: |
        <SchemaDefinition schemaRef="../components/schemas/Test_schema.yaml" />
```

Based on how SchemaDefinition is used in the Petstore example at https://github.com/Redocly/redoc/blob/master/demo/openapi.yaml

Answer (score 0):

See also: [Is there a way to import test files into redoc x-codeSamples source field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71243886/is-there-a-way-to-import-test-files-into-redoc-x-codesamples-source-field)

The following should do the trick:

```
                label: 'Schema'
                source: {$ref: ../components/schemas/Test_schema.yaml}
```