# Is there a way to import test files into redoc x-codeSamples source field?

Tags: api, swagger, documentation, openapi, redoc

The redoc guide specifies using raw text as source in a code sample:
https://github.com/Redocly/redoc/blob/master/docs/redoc-vendor-extensions.md#x-codeSamples
like so:

```
lang: JavaScript
source: console.log('Hello World');
```

however I would like to keep my OpenApi3.0 YAML a living document, so would prefer to actually import code directly from test files, ex:

```
lang: JavaScript
source: #/tests/js_api_test.js
```

where the contents of `js_api_test.js` is just:

```
console.log('Hello World');
```

this way the imported code could be *guaranteed* to work as long as the tests are passing - keeping the document living.

Given I am already relying on generating lots of boilerplate off of the YAML file it seems ideal to keep all aspects of the file living.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

found answer:

```
                label: 'Python'
                source: {$ref: test.py}
```

will import the relative path file test.py there